# Difference between my yaml file that i verify in swagger editor and swageer ui with spring doc

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have diff thing that is not shown in my swagger UI but it is written in my yaml file in the code.
I use spring doc for the génération of the UI.
for exemple i have multiple response http 200, 201 and i only see the 200
the description is not show also. i have ok instead of my description,...[swaggerui-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4qS2.png)

```
responses:
        200:
          description: 'The assessment already exist'
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/AssessmentResponse'
        201:
          description: 'The assessment is created'
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/AssessmentResponse'
```

i would like to show the multiple http  200 and the description.